# If A~B then Fin(A)~Fin(B)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How to prove if there is a bijective function A to  B, then There is a bijection between Fin(A) and Fin(B)?

statement: If A~B, then Fin(A) ~ Fin(B)?
 Fin(A): the set of all subsets of A.
A~B: there exists a bijection A to B.

Thank you guys!

Comment: Suppose $\phi:A\to B$ is a bijection. Can you think of a way to use that to create a correspondence between finite subsets of $A$ and finite subsets of $B$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\phi \colon A \to B$ be a bijection and let
$$
\Phi \colon \operatorname{Fin}(A) \to \operatorname{Fin(B)}, X \mapsto \{ \phi(x) \mid x \in X \}.
$$

To verify that $\Phi$ is indeed a bijection from $\operatorname{Fin}(A)$ to $\operatorname{Fin}(A)$, you have to verify several things:

1. For all $X \in \operatorname{Fin}(A)$ we have that $\Phi(X) \in \operatorname{Fin}(B)$,
2. $\Phi$ is a function (which is quite obvious),
3. $\Phi$ is injective (use the injectivity of $\phi$) and
4. $\Phi$ is surjective (use the surjectivity of $\phi$).